# How to use MySQL Embedded in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: c++, mysql, boost-thread, embedded-database

I am writing a program that uses MySQLe as embedded backend. The database library is owned by an object called "Domain". This Domain object runs within the main thread.

The program launches another thread running a XML-RPC server (boost::thread and xmlrpc_c::serverAbyss). It is linked to the Domain object.

When the XML-RPC server makes the Domain object execute an SQL query the program crashes:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
[Switching to process 73191]
[Switching to process 73191]
Xcode could not locate source file: regex.cpp (line: 74)
```

When the master thread calls Domain object's method that executes SQL queries the program still runs.

```
/*
 * Ports listening
 *
 * - create a Rpc_Server object
 * - create a dedicated thread
 */
Rpc_Server      server(&domain, &conf_params, &router);
boost::thread   server_thread(boost::bind(&Rpc_Server::run, &server)); // This thread makes the server crash

/*
 * Domain routine
 *
 * - Check for ready jobs every minute
 */
while (1) {
    v_jobs jobs = domain.get_ready_jobs(conf_params.get_param("node_name")); // This method does NOT make the server crash
    sleep(60);
}
```

Both the Domain object's methods and the Database object's methods lock a mutex to avoid multi access.

```
bool    Mysql::execute(const std::string* query) {
    MYSQL_RES*  res;
    MYSQL_ROW   row;

    if ( query == NULL )
        return false;

    this->updates_mutex.lock();

    std::cout << query->c_str() << std::endl;

    if ( mysql_query(this->mysql, query->c_str()) != 0 ) {
        std::cerr << query << std::endl << mysql_error(this->mysql);
        UNLOCK_MUTEX;
        return false;
    }

    res = mysql_store_result(this->mysql);
    if (res)
        while ( ( row = mysql_fetch_row(res) ) )
            for ( uint i=0 ; i < mysql_num_fields(res) ; i++ ) 
                std::cout << row[i] << std::endl;
    else
        if ( mysql_field_count(this->mysql) != 0 ) {
            std::cerr << "Erreur : " << mysql_error(this->mysql) << std::endl;
            mysql_free_result(res);
            this->updates_mutex.unlock();
            return false;
        }

    mysql_free_result(res);
    this->updates_mutex.unlock();

    return true;
}


bool    Domain::add_node(const std::string* running_node, const std::string* n, const int* w) {
    std::string query;

    this->updates_mutex.lock();
    query = "START TRANSACTION;";
    if ( this->database.execute(&query) == false ) {
        this->updates_mutex.unlock();
        return false;
    }

    query = "REPLACE INTO node (node_name,node_weight) VALUES ('";
    query += n->c_str();
    query += "','";
    query += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*w);
    query += "');";

    if ( this->database.execute(&query) == false ) {
        query = "ROLLBACK;";
        this->database.execute(&query);
        this->updates_mutex.unlock();
        return false;
    }

    query = "COMMIT;"
    if ( this->database.execute(&query) == false ) {
        this->updates_mutex.unlock();
        return false;
    } else
        this->updates_mutex.unlock();

    return true;
}
```

The MySQLe is created there:

```
bool    Mysql::prepare(const std::string* node_name, const std::string* db_skeleton) {
    static char* server_args[] = {"this_program","--datadir=."};
    static char* server_groups[] = {"embedded","server","this_program_SERVER",(char *)NULL};
    std::string query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ");

    // DB init
    if ( mysql_library_init(sizeof(server_args) / sizeof(char *), server_args, server_groups) )
        std::cerr << "could not initialize MySQL library" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "mysql init..." << std::endl;
    if ( (this->mysql = mysql_init(NULL)) == NULL )
        std::cerr << mysql_error(this->mysql) << std::endl;

    if ( ! mysql_thread_safe() ) {
        std::cerr << "MySQL is NOT theadsafe !" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    mysql_options(this->mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "embedded");
    mysql_options(this->mysql, MYSQL_OPT_USE_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION, NULL);

    mysql_real_connect(this->mysql, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

    // Creates the schema
    query += this->translate_into_db(node_name);
    query += ";";

    if ( this->execute(&query) == false )
        return false;

    // Creates the schema
    query = "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ";
    query += this->translate_into_db(node_name);
    query += " DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1;";

    this->execute(&query);

    // Uses it
    query = "USE " + this->translate_into_db(node_name) + ";";

    this->execute(&query);

    // Loads the skeleton from file
    return this->load_file(db_skeleton->c_str());
}
```

Am I wrong somewhere?
Do you have an example to show me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. Each thread needs to initialize the MySQL environment. That is to say execute some mysql_* functions.

Here are the modified / new methods :

```
bool    Mysql::atomic_execute(const std::string* query) {
    MYSQL_RES*  res;
    MYSQL_ROW   row;
    boost::regex    empty_string("^\\s+$", boost::regex::perl);

    if ( query == NULL )
        return false;

    if ( query->empty() == true or boost::regex_match(*query, empty_string) == true ) {
        std::cerr << "Error : query is empty !" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    this->updates_mutex.lock();

    if ( mysql_query(this->mysql, query->c_str()) != 0 ) {
        std::cerr << query << std::endl << mysql_error(this->mysql);
        this->updates_mutex.unlock();;
        return false;
    }

    res = mysql_store_result(this->mysql);
    if (res)
        while ( ( row = mysql_fetch_row(res) ) )
            for ( uint i=0 ; i < mysql_num_fields(res) ; i++ ) 
                std::cout << row[i] << std::endl;
    else
        if ( mysql_field_count(this->mysql) != 0 ) {
            std::cerr << "Erreur : " << mysql_error(this->mysql) << std::endl;
            mysql_free_result(res);
            this->updates_mutex.unlock();
            return false;
        }

    mysql_free_result(res);
    this->updates_mutex.unlock();

    return true;
}

bool    Mysql::standalone_execute(const v_queries* queries) {
    MYSQL*      local_mysql = this->init();
    std::string query       = "START TRANSACTION;";

    if ( this->atomic_execute(&query) == false ) {
        mysql_close(local_mysql);
        return false;
    }

    BOOST_FOREACH(std::string q, *queries) {
        std::cout << q.c_str() << std::endl;
        if ( this->atomic_execute(&q) == false ) {
            query = "ROLLBACK";
            this->atomic_execute(&query);
            mysql_close(local_mysql);
            return false;
        }
    }

    query = "COMMIT";

    if ( this->atomic_execute(&query) == false ) {
        mysql_close(local_mysql);
        return false;
    }

    mysql_close(local_mysql);
    return true;
}

MYSQL*      Mysql::init() {
    MYSQL*  local_mysql;

    local_mysql = mysql_init(this->mysql);
    mysql_options(this->mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "embedded");
    mysql_options(this->mysql, MYSQL_OPT_USE_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION, NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(local_mysql, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

    return local_mysql;
}
```

The atomic_execute method is used to send single queries to the server.

The standalone_execute method initializes a connection and a transaction, then it sends the whole queries to the server using atomic_execute.

I do not know if a ROLLBACK is useful in case of COMMIT's failure...

The code might need some improvements but it works.